# EXCEL VBA: How to put together multiple different macros into one main macro without errors?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am still new to VBA and have been trying to create one macro that performs multiple sub macros. I am having a lot of difficulty with this process. Every time I run my code I get:

> Error 1004: 'Application'-defined or 'Object'-defined error.

Here is my code for my macro:

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = Worksheets("mac3")

Sheets.Add.Name = "Table"
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
sheet.UsedRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Table!R3C1", TableName:="Pvt" _
, DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

    Sheets("Table").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pvt").PivotFields("Gas")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pvt").PivotFields("Dash")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pvt").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Pvt").PivotFields("Qty"), "Sum of Qty", xlSum
    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, _
        False, True, False, False)
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line to do get an error on?

Comment: That's a fair bit of code relying on preset workbooks and worksheets, it'd be a good idea for you to step through the code using breakpoints and / or F8 and locate the troublesome area, you might see exactly where the problem is and, if not, you're much more likely to get help if you can narrow down the problem!

Comment: @jamheadart haha I know I should narrow it down. How do I find what line of code is the problem? sorry still don't know all the features

Comment: If you get an error pop up, you should be able to click on "debug" and it'll highlight the line in yellow where the error is? Or you can add break points in your code to go through sections: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/images/debugging/set-breakpoint.png ... finally you can step through code line by line using F8 (just click on the Sub RunAll() line and press F8 to run code line by line)

Comment: I started running it line by line and it just kept looping through these lines in macro 16: _If vDB(i, 1) > 0 Then
            vR(i, 1) = Format(vDB(i, 1), "mmmm")
        End If
    Next I_

Comment: @jamheadart At first I had the macros split up into do different worksheets, but I decided it would be better in the longrun to have it be one entire macro. So I combined them, and then these errors started popping up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calling the macros fine the issue is most likely be with one of the macros.

Run your runall sub step by step and then you will see which one throws the error.

If none of the subs will throw an error when you are running them individually, then
 add some delay between two problematic calls.

Comment: How do I add delay? Also, I think there is something wrong with this code:  `Sub macro5()
    Worksheets("info1").UsedRange.AutoFilter _
    Field:=7, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & 4400000000#, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:="<5600000000", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End Sub`  Everything seems to be running smoothly until this macro is called

Comment: Go to your runall sub, add a break point to every line by pressing F9 or clicking right left to the code. Then start running it line by line, by pressing F5. If you there's an error you'll see it, and hit debug to see which line is causing the issue.

Comment: I've located the issue: `ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
sheet.UsedRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Table!R3C1", TableName:="Pvt" _
, DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14` any suggestions?

Comment: The pivot creating part works fine for me. What is the version of your excel?

Comment: Microsoft Excel 2010

Comment: I think you should use macro recorder to record the pivot creating, and tweak that after.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the call of the next Macro just before the `End Sub` of the previous Macro so the last line of your first macro `CombineWorkbooks` would look like below. Instead of calling them all at the start.

```
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
'7:Locate the dates two lines above this line.Update the dates to the last day of the months from which you want data from the stated worksheet from workbook1
Call AddWorksheet
End Sub
```

Also would it make a difference if you made all the sub public subs?

Comment: I keep getting error 1004 for my CreatePivotTable macro.